# Java database connect in 2 classes

Tags: java, mysql

Hi everyone in my project I have 2 classes a Login Class and a Sports Class. And I want to pull a specific field from the database in the Sports Class based on the user login.

So for example if my login is 12345 the database should pull the respective sport name based on my login.

How do I connect the 2 classes in such a way so that the database can pull data based on my login in the previous class?

Comment: Provide simple UML diagram first then we can suggest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a singleton class and store user details in that class when login happened and later you can access that from any other class.

```
public class UserDetails{
   private static UserDetails instance = new UserDetails();
   private UserDetails(){}
   private String userId;
   public static UserDetails getInctance(){
        return instance;
   }
   public String getUserId(){
        return userId;
   }
   public void setUserId(String userId){
       this.userId = userId;
   }
}
```

Then in Login class,

```
UserDetails.getInctance().setUserId("12345");
```

In Sports Class,

```
String userId = UserDetails.getInctance().getUserId();
```

Then user userId in query.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming time of calling you have the user information.Then simply you can get the userid and pass as method argument to sports detail method.Try to make classes loosely coupled.